# Get the generatedkey() for a composite key

Tags: java, sql, primary-key

I've got a little problem I don't know how to get the different keys during the creation of a new instance in SQL.

Here's my code :

```
ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

PreparedStatement req = laConnexion.prepareStatement("insert into Abonnement 
(id_client,id_revue,date_debut,date_fin) value(?,?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            req.setInt(1, a1.getIdCl());
            req.setInt(2, a1.getIdRev());
            req.setDate(3, dateS);
            req.setDate(4, dateU);

            req.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = req.getGeneratedKeys();

            while (rs.next()) {
                 keys.add(rs.getInt(1));
                 keys.add(rs.getInt(2));
            }
```

I only used this kind of code for simple primary key not for composite one. I just tried to adapt it to get several keys but it doesn't work.

My Object is ABONNEMENT(int **id_customer**, int **id_review**, LocalDate first_date, LocalDate last_date)

Comment: What is the primary key for database table `ABONNEMENT` ?

Comment: id_customer and id_review

Comment: Then your `INSERT` statement, in the java code you posted, is wrong. Is the column name `id_client` (as you wrote in the java code) or `id_customer` (as you wrote in the comment) ? A generated key means the database provides the value and not your code, so the `INSERT` statement should not contain the primary key columns.